# How to initialize a smart-table with a sorted colunm or trigger a sort from javascript?

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I'm using [Smart-Table](https://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) and would like it to have its initial state with a specific column sorted. I could of course sort the data myself by that column but the Smart-Table won't reflect that and it would be double work too.

I would also be happy with calling a function like `smartTable.sortBy("columnName")` which I could call upon displaying the view but of course this function doesn't exist.

Comment: Not familiar with Smart-Table but isn't what the [`st-sort` attribute](https://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#section-sort) for?

Comment: Thanks, the st-sort attribute simply marks the column as sorteable and takes the colunm name (or object getter) to use.